# How to convert postgresql dump file into mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pg-dump

I having Postgresql dump file like data.sql. I need to convert postgresql file into mysql dump file It is possible to convert without install postgresql database . Thanks in advance

Comment: PostgreSQL and mysql have incompatible features that could not be translatable. Perhaps your best bet would be to edit the file and do any adjustments manually for any incompatible features (e.g. functions, different datatypes, etc).

Comment: can u tell me how to edit?

Comment: The sql file is a text file, you can edit it with any text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard, which was introduced in MySQL Workbench 5.2.41.

There's a blog post on the MySQL Workbench site [here](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2012/11/how-to-migrate-postgresql-databases-to-mysql-using-the-mysql-workbench-migration-wizard/) that details how to perform a migration.

Note that it will not be able to migrate more complicated database features.

Comment: [According to a new user Jason](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218003/67785), who can't post comments yet: "The above post is not answering the question. The OP wanted to avoid installing Postgresql and wanted to migrate from a dump. MySQL Workbench can only migrate from a running instance."